# Retrieve data from access database to data grid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, datetimepicker

I try to read a data from access database with specific date to datagrid view in VB.NET. I use a datetime picker for that. Below code i used for retreive data. But i press the find button. nothing display in datagrid view. this is the code

```
Private Sub BTNFIND_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNFIND.Click
    ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Clear()
    getConnect()
    'Dim editdate As String
    DTPEDITAT.Value = Format(DTPEDITAT.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    'MessageBox.Show(DTPEDITAT.Value)
    'editdate = DTPEDITAT.Value
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = " & DTPEDITAT.Value & " ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "ATTENDANCE")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("ATTENDANCE")
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim atstat As String
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            If row("AT_STATUS") = 1 Then
                atstat = "Present"
            ElseIf row("AT_STATUS") = 0 Then
                atstat = "Absent"
            ElseIf row("AT_STATUS") = 0.5 Then
                atstat = "Halfday"
            Else
                atstat = "Error"
            End If
            'MessageBox.Show(row("EMP_ID"))
            'MessageBox.Show(row("EMP_NAME"))
            'MessageBox.Show(atstat)
            'MessageBox.Show(row("AT_REMARK"))
            Me.ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Add(row("EMP_ID"))
            Me.ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Add(row("EMP_NAME"))
            Me.ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Add(atstat)
            Me.ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Add(row("AT_REMARK"))
        Next row
        ATCEDITGRID.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Sr.No."
        Me.ATCEDITGRID.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(3)
        ATCEDITGRID.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        AddRowHeadersEdit()
        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "DB Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

please check the code. and give me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a sql command concatenating strings you expose your code to two big problems.

- First, you could write the wrong syntax for particular datatype on a
  particular database
- Second, you expose your code to Sql Injection attacks from a
  malicious user (well, here should not be a concern, but....)

Instead build a parametrized query and let the framework code interact with the database engine in a secure and correct way

So you should write:

```
    Conn.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK " & _ 
                           "FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = ? ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", DTPEDITAT.Value)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "ATTENDANCE")
```

Now looking at your code you could have another potential error in the way you treat the value of the field AT_STATUS. From your code it seems that the field is of type decimal or double. If your code compile then you have probably set the [OPTION STRICT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to OFF. It is a better practice to keep this option ON and convert appropriately the datatypes

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("ATTENDANCE")
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim atstat As String
    Dim status as Decimal

    For Each row In dt.Rows
        status = Convert.ToDecimal(row("AT_STATUS"))
        If status = 1 Then
            atstat = "Present"
        ElseIf status  = 0 Then
            atstat = "Absent"
        ElseIf status  = 0.5 Then
            atstat = "Halfday"
        Else
            atstat = "Error"
        End If
        ......
    Next row
```